# Dreams of the future in Slam?

Tags: slam, nick-hornby

In Nick Hornby's novel Slam, the main character, Sam, narrates his story which happened in the past.  In the story, he recounts one or two dreams where he is transported to a day in the future.  Then what happens around him in reality in the future seems to be uncannily similar to what was in his dream (e.g., the name of a child, a certain person he would recognize from his dream that he hadn't met at the time of the dream).

**Are these dreams intended by Hornby to be supernatural?**

Note: nothing else in the novel seems supernatural, but at least to me these dreams do.  (And I don't recall anything supernatural in any other of Hornby's novels, though this book seems aimed at a younger audience than his other works.)  Possibly they are intended to be supernatural, or perhaps meant to be ambiguous.  One possible explanation is that this is just Sam's story and the Sam of the future remembers his dreams in a different way than he dreamt them.  This seems not so unreasonable to me as Sam does not seem completely grounded in reality himself (though much more so by the end of the book).